# Nested views in Backbonejs, a post & comments relation

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Array Of Objects

The data is received from server

```
var Updates = [
{"post_id":"1","post_desc":"This is my first  post",
     "comments":[{"id":1,"comment":"some comments","like":7},
                 {"id":9,"comment":"some   comments","like":3}
                ]
},
{"post_id":"2","post_desc":"This is my second  post",
     "comments":[{"id":5,"comment":"some comments","like":5}]
}]
```

Model:

```
var Update = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{
    photo: "default.png"
   }
 });
```

Collection:

```
var latestUpdates = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Update
});
```

Single View:

```
var UpdateView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "div",
className: "post-container",
template: $("#postTemplate").html(),

render: function () {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);

    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
});
```

Master view:

```
var UpdatesView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: $("#postContainer"),

initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new latestUpdates(Updates);
    this.render();
},
render: function () {
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
        that.renderUpdates(item);
    }, this);
},
renderUpdates: function (item) {
    var updateView = new UpdateView({
        model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(updateView.render().el);
}

});

//create app instance
var wallUpdates = new UpdatesView();
```

How can I render comments section under each post?
Trying to achieve layout similar to facebook post-comment system

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a `CommentListView`, owned by your `UpdateView`. `tagName: "ul", className: "post-comments"`

Then have a `CommentView` owned by the `CommentListView`. CommentView's render should not append anything to the DOM, but return its `$el`.

`CommentListView` would tell each of the `CommentView`'s to render, appending each of their `$el`'s to the `CommentListView`'s `$el`.

For the containers, I'd use:

```
<div class="post-container" data-post-id="<%= YourPostId %>">
    <div class="post-body">
        <!--Your post can go in here-->
    </div>
    <ul class="post-comments">
        <!--Append your comments in here-->
    </ul>
</div>
```